# search in a Datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter, datatable

I am currently working on a project that processing a file and create a datatble and create a "excel" look data grid view for the processed results. 
The flow is open a new file and click process. After that, the datagridview will show a table with processed data. The following is the function to create a table and input the values for each columns.

```
public DataTable createDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Date Time");
        dt.Columns.Add("CAT Protocol");
        dt.Columns.Add("Display");
        //dt.Columns.Add("Command ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Command Description");

        List<string> timeList = time();
        List<string> catList = read(userSelectedFilePath);
        List<string> displayList = translate(catList);
        List<string> idList = commandID(catList);
        List<string> descList = commandDescription(idList);


        int rows = catList.Count();

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            DataRow _myRow = dt.NewRow();
            _myRow["Date Time"] = timeList.ElementAt(i);
            _myRow["CAT Protocol"] = catList.ElementAt(i);
            _myRow["Display"] = displayList.ElementAt(i);
            //_myRow["Command ID"] = idList.ElementAt(i);
            _myRow["Command Description"] = descList.ElementAt(i);
            dt.Rows.Add(_myRow);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Then the user can use "Find" function which will refresh the results based on the users' input. When user choose Find, a textbox will pop out. When user press enter, the datatable will be refreshed based on Command Description.
I think I need to write some code in this function.

```
 private void TextBoxKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            //write something here
        }
    }
```

Here is the screenshot of my interface. 
[image]
My question is how to implement find function in this application. I will really appreciate all kinds of help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use LINQ to get all your indices of the corresponding lines:

```
var indices = descList.Select((desc, index) => new { desc, index = index }).Where(item => item .desc.Contains(SearchTextBox.Text)).Select(item => item.index).ToList();
```

Then clear your `DataGridView`and readd all those items with the indices, you get.

```
for (int i = 0; i < indices.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow _myRow = dt.NewRow();
    _myRow["Date Time"] = timeList.ElementAt(indices[i]);
    _myRow["CAT Protocol"] = catList.ElementAt(indices[i]);
    _myRow["Display"] = displayList.ElementAt(indices[i]);
    //_myRow["Command ID"] = idList.ElementAt(indices[i]);
    _myRow["Command Description"] = descList.ElementAt(indices[i]);
    dt.Rows.Add(_myRow);
}
```

Furthermore I'd suggest you build a class for each row:

```
public class LogLine{
    public DateTime Date {get;set;} //maybe Convert to DateTime or change to string
    public string Protocol {get;set;}
    public string Display {get;set;}
    public string Command {get;set;}
}
```

Later you can simply use `List<LogLine>` to populate your `DataGridView`.

This will make your code cleaner, and will simplify much of the code.